# tqdm crashes on Windows console upon accidental mouse/keyboard input

Tags: python, windows, tqdm

Running any application on Windows that make use of `tqdm` progress bars has become a tremendous headache.

It's not clear to me if this is a Windows fault or not, but the bug is easily reproducible. Run the following code on **cmd.exe** or **Powershell**:

```
from tqdm import *
import time

counter = 1000
for i in tqdm(range(counter)):
     time.sleep(.01)
```

You can do the following while the progress bar is increasing to trigger the crash:

- Use the *left-mouse* button to select a few characters on the window (even blank spaces will do, as the screenshot below demonstrates) and then either *right-click* or press any key to crash the application:

[image]

The error message says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tqdmTest.py", line 5, in <module>
    for i in tqdm(range(counter)):
  File "C:\Users\brcod\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\tqdm\_tqdm.py", line 979, in __iter__
    sp(self.__repr__())
  File "C:\Users\brcod\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\tqdm\_tqdm.py", line 241, in print_status
    fp_write('\r' + s + (' ' * max(last_len[0] - len_s, 0)))
  File "C:\Users\brcod\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\tqdm\_tqdm.py", line 234, in fp_write
    fp.write(_unicode(s))
OSError: raw write() returned invalid length 306 (should have been between 0 and 153)
```

I'm using **Python 3.4.4** on **Windows 10** with **tqdm 4.19.5**.

This is very annoying because the mouse accidentally selects a few characters in the window when I'm just trying to click on it to focus the window.

Can anyone clarify why this happens? Is there a proper workaround for this problem?

Comment: [I also reported this issue on tqdm's Github page](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/505).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**: the most simple solution for this problem is to disable *QuickEdit Mode* in the properties of the **cmd.exe** window to prevent mouse clicks from accidentally selecting and pasting text:

[image]

**Solution 2**: this can also be handled programmatically. Just rewrite the loop to catch the exception and `pass` it when it happens:

```
from tqdm import *
import time

maxCount = 1000
pbar = tqdm(total = maxCount)

for i in range(maxCount+1):
     try:
          pbar.update(i - pbar.n)
     except OSError as e:
          pass

     time.sleep(.01)

pbar.close()
```